# Writing recursive solutions to a list

Tags: python, list, function, recursion

I am trying to write a function that will return a list of the first n catalan numbers. This is what I have come up with so far.

```
def catalan_numbers(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        n -= 1
        return int((((2*n+2) * (2*n+1))/((n+1)*(n+2))) * catalan_numbers(n))
```

So far this provide me with a correct solution for a single index. So if I were to call `catalan_numbers(4)`, 14 would be returned which is correct but exactly what I am seeking. I tried to fix this issue doing the following:

```
def catalan_numbers(n):
    catalan = [1]
    for x in range(0, n):
        catalan.append(int((((2*n+2) * (2*n+1))/((n+1)*(n+2))) * catalan_numbers(n))
    return catalan
```

But this returns:

```
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

Comment: You are forgetting to add a base case for the second recursive function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest iteration over recursion:

```
def catalan_numbers(N):
    C = [1]
    for n in range(1, N):
        C.append((4*n - 2) * C[-1] // (n + 1))
    return C
```

Answer (score 1):

the error is because you don't have a base case also check the following code instead of returning a one number it returns a list and concatenate the current n catalan number with the list for n-1

```
def catalan_numbers(n):
    if n == 0:
        return [1]
    else:
        n -= 1
        t = catalan_numbers(n)
        return t + [int((((2*n+2) * (2*n+1))/((n+1)*(n+2))) * t[-1])]
```